# Part of line flushed left and part flushed right in Vim

Tags: vim

I am wondering if there is a way to make Vim flush part of a line left and part of a line right.  So `:left` flushes the line under the cursor left, and `:right` flushes the line under the cursor right, but I would like to be able to make a line, say

```
left text right text
```

be justified left until some point, and right afterwards, so if the linewidth is set to, 78 say, then it should become:

```
left text                                                           right text
```

Not that important, but in the same line of thought: it would also be nice to do the same with left, right and center, such that

```
left text center text right text
```

could easily be made into

```
left text                        center text                        right text
```

I guess the first part is probably easier, and it is also the part I am most interested in, but if there is a solution to the second part, then that would be nice as well.

Also, I should mention, ideally I would like a solution for which the cursor position determines where the break should occur, but it could also be that you provide a column number, or something else.  It should at least be a solution that is easier than to actually put the spaces there yourself.

Comment: the requirement isn't that clear to me. 1) the center text example, how do you control the output was the one in your Q, but not `left (boundary)     text center text right  (boundary)        text`?  by cmd arguments? visual selection? 2) the length of a "line" is always same as your screen width? what if a line has 99999 char long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [AlignFromCursor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4155) plugin provides just that: Commands and mappings that align left and right (sorry, no center) from the cursor position.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late acceptance, but it sliped my mind.  Thanks for the reply, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for, and I will try to use the script next time.  Best, Kristian

Comment: Better late than never; enjoy the plugin :-)